# How to loop through only the worksheets included in a list?

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to use VBA to loop through worksheets in my file but only those that are included in a list on a control worksheet, e.g.

[Worksheet List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnWag.png)

When I try to look up the worksheet name in this list, it does not recognise the worksheet name as a string.

Current code below:

I create a function to vlookup on the list:

```
 Public Function IsInRunList(WsName As Variant, RunList As Range) As Boolean
   If Application.VLookup(WsName, RunList, 1, False) = WsName Then
   IsInRunList = True
   End If
 End Function
```

Then I call this function in my subroutine:

```
 Dim Ws As Worksheet

  For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsInRunList(Ws.Name, Range("Run_List").Columns(j)) Then
```

I get a mismatch error for Ws.Name here.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of ideas (Loop over all cells, read cells first in an array and loop over that, read cells first in a dictionary or collection and check if key is present, use Find or VLookup). However, I don't understand what you mean with *" it does not recognise the worksheet name as a string"* - show your code and maybe we can help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added some code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub iterateBetweenSheetInList()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sh.Name
             Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet7"
                 Debug.Print sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                 'your code can do here whatever you need...
        End Select
   Next
End Sub
```

Or a version to take the sheets name from a range (in column X:X in the code example). You did not show us in which column the sheets list exists:

```
Sub iterateBetweenSheetInListBis()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, arrSh As Variant, El As Variant
   Set sh = ActiveSheet

   'adapt the next range with the lettr of your column where the sheets name exists:
   arrSh = sh.Range("X2:X" & sh.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Value
   For Each El In arrSh
        Set ws = Worksheets(El)
        Debug.Print ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'do here whatever you need...
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Would I have to specify the sheet names in the code? E.g. "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc. The names in the list should be able to change so I would need the code to be able to read in what is included in the list. Edit: Sorry I am just seeing your edit, I will try that thanks!

Comment: @Fawk_Nin: First version needs to make the list in code. The second one takes them from the sheet. But, I am afraid that, in the worksheet somebody must also maintain the list... Please refresh the page (this one) and copy the updated code for the second version. And take care to change "X" with your appropriate column letter.

Comment: @Fawk_Nin: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody supplies a solution to our question, tick the code left side check box making it the **accepted answer**. In this way,  somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Answer (score 0):

`Application.VLookup` returns a `Range` when successful and an error if not (same behavior as in Excel). An error is not a string, it's a special type that you can check with `IsError`.

Change your checking routine to something like:

```
 Public Function IsInRunList(WsName As Variant, RunList As Range) As Boolean
    Dim res As Variant
    res = Application.VLookup(WsName, RunList, 1, False)
    IsInRunList = Not IsError(res)
 End Function
```